# Specify shader instruction count in OpenCV DNN class using OpenCL

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu, shader, opencl

We are using the `cv::dnn::Net` class from OpenCV to perform image processing.

Here is the framework of the code with an indication of what causes the break:

```
cv::dnn::Net NeuralNetwork;   
...
// This works fine since it keeps OpenCV code running on the CPU
// NeuralNetwork.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_CPU);    
// This change leads to a segmentation fault since it allows OpenCV to use the GPU
NeuralNetwork.setPreferableTarget(cv::dnn::DNN_TARGET_OPENCL);
... 
// Segmentation fault occurs here
NeuralNetwork.forward(PredictedBoxesAndMasks, OutputLayerNames);
```

**Error:**

*Shader has too many instructions: 689 (maximum is 512)

Status -1016: Unknown OpenCL error

Failed to compile kernel:

BASIC_k7x7_cn3_g3_s2x2_d1x1_b0_in256x256_p2x2_num1_M8_activ0_eltwise0_FP32_4_1_1_1

(long list of OpenCL definitions)

errmsg: Segmentation fault*

OpenCV recognizes the GPU and returns this information:

*Vendor name: Vivante Corporation

Name: Vivante OpenCL Device GC2000.5108.0000

Driver version: OpenCL 1.1 V6.2.4.p4.190076

available: 1

Global Memory size: 67108864

Memory cache size: 4096

Memory cache type: 2

Local Memory size: 1024

Local Memory type: 2

Max Clock frequency: 528*

**Question:**

How do I limit the number of instructions OpenCV/OpenCL is trying to issue to the GPU?

I haven't seen any other users have this specific problem. I am guessing it is not popular to run heavyweight neural networks on embedded systems.

Thanks for your time & help!

Comment: Are you trying to run the whole network, from input to output layer, in a single cv::dnn::Net::forward call? Is it possible for you to break it up into several smaller layers, then run these layers with cv::dnn::Net::forward and combine them to get the desired output? That way, you won't exceed the max shader instructions for a cv::dnn::Net::forward call.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we'll try this and report back. If you post this as an answer I'll assign you the bounty (within the next 24 hr) since no one else has offered any advice.

Comment: It's okay. Let's first see if it helps :)